# Why the function got by idapython is not the same as displayed in function window using IDA?

Tags: binary, disassembly, ida

I was trying to use IDA Pro to analyse a binary writen and compiled by myself on Linux. In the function window, IDA displayed the function `experiment(std::string,int,std::string) .text 00000000004181FB 0000082F 000004D8 00000000 R . . . B . .` But, when I tried to get the function by ida python, .

```
Python>for i in idautils.Functions():
Python>    name =  idaapi.get_func_name(i)
Python>    if name.startswith('_Z10experimentSsiSs') or name.startswith('experiment'):
Python>        print name
Python>        print idc.GetType(i)
```

the result is

`_Z10experimentSsiSs
None`

no function is named as `experiment`, and the type of function `_Z10experimentSsiSs` (it seems that it is the function `experiment()`) is None. I want to get the arguments of all functions, but as mentioned above， I can not get the function's infomation (_Z10experimentSsiSs), and even i can not find the function (experiment). Why is this? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, `idc.getType` only work with C functions. As you're using C++ the name is [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C++).

Here's a quick test I did:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


void test(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    std::cout << s1 << " " << s2 << std::endl;

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "2 args needed" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    test(argv[1], argv[2]);

    return 0;    
}
```

Compile, test:

```
neitsa@eagle:/mnt/temp/gpp$ g++ -o test test.cpp
neitsa@eagle:/mnt/temp/gpp$ ./test hello world
hello world
```

In IDA (I'm using 7.2), I have this (monstrosity) for the `test` function:

```
.text:0000000000000CBA ; test(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&)
.text:0000000000000CBA                 public _Z4testRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES6_
.text:0000000000000CBA _Z4testRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES6_ proc near
```

So, technically the (mangled) function name is: `_Z4testRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES6_`

As the type of the arguments is provided by the [symbolic information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol) (i.e if you strip your binary you don't have access to this information anymore! except in the case of [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) which can also provide this type of information) the only way to get them is to demangle the name and then parse it:

Get the name:

```
Python>idaapi.get_func_name(0xcba)
_Z4testRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES6_
```

Demangle it:

```
Python>idc.Demangle(idaapi.get_func_name(0xcba), idc.GetLongPrm(idc.INF_SHORT_DN))
test(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> const&,std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> const&)
```

Once you have that you can parse the function prototype and extract the parameters types (which might not be an easy fit with C++...).

You might want to try with `INF_LONG_DN` which seems to add spaces after each argument. That might help when parsing:

```
Python>idc.Demangle(idaapi.get_func_name(0xcba), idc.GetLongPrm(idc.INF_LONG_DN))
test(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&)
```

Note: do try with `strip <program> -o <program_stripped>` you'll see that the name of the function will simply not be here anymore.